# Which one is grammatically correct: "use cup as a measurement system" or "use cup as measurement system"?

Tags: as

The question is whether there should be an indefinite article *a* before measurement or not. In general, "as a something, we use something else" or "as something, we use something else"? This also raises the question that in the case that *a* should be used, then what happens if *something* is uncountable. Another example could be "use speed as (a) performance metric of a car" (instead of using acceleration or handling for instance).

Comment: Why not "use a cup to measure"? I'm not sure  what you mean by "use a cup as a measurement". A measurement is an amount obtained by measuring something, or the act of measuring (Her measurement of the effect was very precise.)

Comment: You're right. I should edit my question to "measurement system". That's what I meant. Another instance can be "use speed as (a) performance metric of a car".

Comment: Your second example is more grammatical (or at least more idiomatic) than the first, so ignoring the side discussion about cups: yes, an article is required; ‘the’ might be appropriate, if only one metric is in use.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically you need "a" for the countable noun "system". "The" is also possible.

"Cup" isn't a measurement system.   So both phrases are equally non-idiomatic.

You might say "I use 'cups' to measure volume."

Comment: Well, to be very exact, cup itself can be a system. Even if we consider it as only one thing (not to mention the container and the handle), the definition of system is a group of things. Now, the group can be a group of one only, but anyway, the point of my question is the grammar, not the meaning, so, is it the same for *speed* in the other phrase as well?

Comment: Not really.  "cup" is just one unit.  One unit does not a system make.

Comment: I agree with @JamesK: a cup isn't a system, it is a device that can be used in a system. It is fair to say that “using a cup” is a measur**ing** system

Comment: “We measure volume in cups.”